# what does the number mean in the middle of the http header and content

Tags: sockets, network-programming, http-headers

I'm writing a program that is similar to a browser but much more simple.  The user types a link and the program saves it to a file in local.

I sent an http header like this:

```
GET /index.php HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: www.highradio.tw\r\n
\r\n
```

then I received:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 16 Apr 2011 14:16:29 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8q mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.1 PHP/5.2.5 (x64)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.5 (x64)
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=d0ug0im94rg7lrjp40h38vo784; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html

204a
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
....
```

What does the number (in HEX?) `204a` mean?

When I use Chrome or `wget` in terminal, the `204a` doesn't show up.

Comment: I print out the first received 1024 bytes. I haven't parsed the header out yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That hex value represents the number of bytes in the following chunk.

Check out the [Chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) page on Wikipedia, it will tell you what that number is.

Comment: It is possible to tell server not to send by this mode? (without chunked)

Comment: apart from requesting via HTTP/1.0, I don't know a way to force non-chunked encoding.

Comment: Wiki says "For version 1.1 of the HTTP protocol, the chunked transfer mechanism is considered to be always acceptable". Thanks.